# Rectangle to Thumb template in uwp

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am creating a rectangle dynamically which has to be added to the Thumb template. In Wpf I do the following. But in UWP, it says it can't find the FrameworkElementFactory part of the PresentationFramework.dll. But when I add reference to the dll, it gives a bunch of errors. How can I create a rectangle and assign it to a thumb. Please help.

Code in WPF

```
  public void RectangleToThumb()
        {
            Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
            r.Height = 80;
            r.Width = 150;
            r.Fill = Brushes.Red;
            ControlTemplate t = new ControlTemplate();
            var rectangle = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Rectangle));
            rectangle.SetValue(Rectangle.HeightProperty, r.Height);
            rectangle.SetValue(Rectangle.WidthProperty, r.Width);
            rectangle.SetValue(Rectangle.FillProperty, r.Fill);
            t.VisualTree = rectangle;

            Thumb th = new Thumb();
            th.Template = t;
            th.DragDelta += Th_DragDelta;
            cnvDemo.Children.Add(th);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Rectangle to Thumb template in uwp

`FrameworkElementFactory` could not support in UWP platform. If we want to make [`ControlTemplate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.controltemplate) for [`Thumb`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.thumb), we need load xaml string as `ControlTemplate` with [`XamlReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.markup.xamlreader) class, for detail please refer the following.

```
public void RectangleToThumb()
{
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
    r.Height = 80;
    r.Width = 150;
    r.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    ControlTemplate t = CreateTemplate();
    Thumb th = new Thumb();
    th.Template = t;
    RootGrid.Children.Add(th);
}
private static ControlTemplate CreateTemplate()
{
    const string xaml = "<ControlTemplate TargetType='Thumb' xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\"><Rectangle  Width = '150' Height = '80'  Fill = 'Red' /></ControlTemplate>";
    var сt = (ControlTemplate)XamlReader.Load(xaml);
    return сt;
}
```